# Which threads can be if we lose constructor?

Tags: javascript

I have such example

```
function test1(){this.a = 1;}
function test2(){this.b = 2;}
function test3(){this.c = 3;}
test2.prototype = Object.create(test1.prototype);
test2.prototype.constructor = test2;
test3.prototype = Object.create(test1.prototype); // lose constructor
var q = new test2();//we can find constructor test2 in __proto__
var q2 = new test3();//there is no such field in __proto__
```

[image]

in q2 link to constructor `test3` was lost.

**Why and how could it influence in the bad way?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you'll get away with that, but I'd recommend you don't. (Not least because I'd recommend using `class` syntax if you're going to use constructor function hierarchies, not ES5-style patterns, and `class` sets things up correctly for you automatically.)

For a long time, although JavaScript *set* the `constructor` property on the default object it assigned to the `prototype` of a function, it didn't **use** it for anything. But userland code sometimes did, for the obvious purpose: To get the constructor function that (probably) constructed an object. As of ES2015, JavaScript itself uses the `constructor` property for that too, in places where it's creating a new object from an existing one, such as a new array from an existing array (for instance, [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)), or a new `RegExp` from an existing `RegExp` (it does that behind the scenes when you use a regular expression in [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)), a new promise from an existing promise (for instance, [`then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)), etc.

So if you leave your hierarchy with the wrong effective `constructor` property, operations expecting it to be correct will fail. But it's rare for an operation to actually use it, if you're not subclassing a built-in (and if you are, again, use `class`) and you don't write code to use `constructor` explicitly, it won't get used for anything.

Comment: Maybe you can add that one implication is breaking the `instanceof` operator

Comment: @MoritzRoessler - `constructor` has nothing to do with `instanceof` (you're not the first to think it does, though). :-) `o instanceof F` checks to see if the object referenced by `F.prototype` appears in `o`'s prototype chain. `constructor` is completely ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Lets take the example.
We can get new array of 1,2,3 in 4 ways;

1. [1,2,3]
2. new Array(1,2,3)
3. Array(1,2,3)
4. new Array.prototype.constructor(1,2,3)

In the last variant we use *constructor*. So if we want new array which creates reversed instance, we will inherit from Array, but if we lose constructor, the 4th will do things in an other way.

```
const myArray = function(){ 
   const args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments); 
   return args.reverse();    
};    
myArray.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype);
console.log(new myArray(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)); //reversed
const newMyArray = new myArray.prototype.constructor(1,2,3,4,5); //not reversed
```